# How to avoid showing zero value on textview of row in array adapter?

Tags: android, model, android-arrayadapter

I have an array adapter with row that have textview1,textview2,textview3
also i have 3 arrays (T1:String,T2:String,T3:int) with model getT1(),getT2(),getT3().

array T3 have this value :{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,...}, this array have so much zero value and I want to not set this zero value on position of textview3.

When I use this method, I see that some position that have zero value, showing some  not zero value item in the row position. What is the problem?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
   final Model model = modelList.get(position);

if (model.getT3()!=0)  { holder.tv3.setText(model.getT3()+"");
...
}
```

Comment: What value you are getting in that row?

Comment: i set this value : {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,...} on to model ...

Comment: values not important for me , i just want to dont set zero value on tv3 ..

Comment: Does your method getT3() return an array?

Comment: yes , i say that all of this method work fine ... just some of zero value show some thing...

Comment: you can not compare an array to an integer `model.getT3()!=0`

Comment: for what ??  it's an integer array ...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70734/discussion-between-kelvincer-and-hossein).

Comment: i'am in chat room ...

Comment: (This question is rather unclear, so I am voting to close on that basis. OP, if you log in again, please clarify it if you can, so others can learn from the problem/solution).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Finally I find problem. Occur random set text or random coloring on item, Because I don't set default tv.setText or setBackgroundColor or ... so every one need to set default set and in if condition you can set your parameter.